# Как создать SFX для распаковки в ProgramFiles?

Tags: winrar

Мне нужно создать SFX архив, который бы при запуске копировал все файлы какую-то папку в ProgramFiles и запускал после этого файл. При этом нужно делать это все без окон. Если делать архив через Winrar, то можно копировать файлы в ProgramFiles, но для этого нужно будет запускать архив и нажимать кнопку Извлечь. Мне же нужно, чтобы все само выполнилось после запуска файла. Такое можно сделать, если я выберу пункт Распаковать во временную папку. В этом случае архив будет сам распаковываться и запускать файл, но сделать такое же с ProgramFiles через Winrar видимо нельзя. Чем же мне сделать то, что мне нужно?

Comment: Под разные языки программирования есть специальные библиотеки для работы с архивами, копайте в эту сторону.

Comment: @Bazinga, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, какие технологии и языки используете и т. д.